# Autolayout: UILabel not resizing properly with long text

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UITableViewCell` with two `UILabel`s: title and description.

I am having problems with the title label. Basically, what I want is to increase its height if the text is bigger than the available space and prevent the "...". This is how it looks, you can see the constraints of the title label on the right.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the title label successfully increase its height but the text still in one line. The font used in "Text Styles - Callout". Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**: I already set number of lines to '0'

**Edit 2**: I fixed by deleting the `UILabel` and adding it again, but first take a look at suggestions made by Wojtek.

Comment: You could execute `yourLabel.sizeToFit()` after set label content.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Thanks, already did that and same result.

Comment: You may need to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth on the UILabel so it knows when to wrap.  It looks like the constraints are depending on the -intrinsicContentSize of the label and that will always be a single line unless you tell it where it must start wrapping (since it needs to figure that out to generate the constraints which in turn define the frame).

Comment: if it is just one label, just give the leading and trailing, and height, don't give any width constraint

Comment: Try executing `yourLabel.updateConstraints()` after `sizeToFit`.  Autolayout is still a nightmare for me so I apologize if doesn't help

Comment: @CarlLindberg Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with the following and didn't work: `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.bounds.size.width`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Executing that makes some weird behavior on the labels height, but never with the result that I expected

Comment: You can't use self.bounds to determine the preferredMaxLayoutWidth -- that might be the bounds from a previous string.  The constraint values *calculate* the bounds/frame, so you can't use that to determine an input ;-)  You might have to use the known size of the superview's width (and would need to update the label value whenever the superview size changes).  But... the label should still be visibly wrapping if there is room for a second line and the number of lines is 0.  Maybe it is not high enough for two rows of text.  Are you setting attributedText or just text?

Comment: @CarlLindberg I am setting just normal text. I tried to make the label taller to see if that was the case, that maybe it hasn't enough space, but I get the same result.

Comment: Actually, it may be that a number of lines of 0 (unlimited) and truncating by tail is not really compatible.  I think that may make UILabel assume it is a single line.  See if making numberOfLines 2 works to at least get it shown.  If it does, you may need to calculate that each time. (NSAttributedStrings can have NSParagraphStyles which have a line wrap mode which thus can override UILabel's, which is why I asked, BTW).

Comment: @CarlLindberg Thanks, I tried that yesterday but it didn't work. I finally fixed by deleting the UILabel and starting from scratch. A shame because I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is supported with Auto-layout on, by following these steps for the UILabels in question.

1. Set number of lines to '0' in the Utilities pane > Attributes inspector.
2. Right click the UILabel and Alt - control (Xcode 7.1 and above) drag to it's superview to set the leading, trailing, top and bottom margin.
3. For auto height and width you can set the priority of the constraint to level '600' with relation 'Greater than or Equal'.

Github example (I only use a different 'relation' for the bottom constraint in the following example. You could also choose to do this for a different constraint i.e. the trailing constraint in your specific case): https://github.com/wojtekdmyszewicz/UILabel

[image]

Comment: Sorry, not working. I forgot to mention that I already set number of lines to 0, I will added to the main post. Setting the top constrain, which was the only one missing, had no effect.

Comment: @estemendoza are you using Auto-layout ?

Comment: @estemendoza and do you have Line Breaks set to 'word wrap' ?

Comment: No, I had it in "Truncate Tail", that's why it display the "..." but I changed to try it and had the same result.

Comment: @estemendoza Maybe try to test it first with only one UILabel and the correct constraints (leading, trailing, bottom, top). And make sure nothing programmatically is conflicting with your constraints.

Comment: Ok, will try. Quick question, do you have any specific value for the constrains? Because I want the label increase it's size not only by it's height but also by it's width, so the constrains can't be just something for example "trailingSpace=10" because that would make the uilabel have always the same width, make sense?

Comment: @estemendoza Yes that's another question ... you will have to decrease the priority level of the constraints in question.

Comment: I changed the priority to the top constrains with no luck. The weird thing is that works fine on the Xcode preview (with or without the priority changed) but not on the simulator.

Comment: @estemendoza I will add an example (github example project) to my answer above. (You need to set priority to 600). Github example: https://github.com/wojtekdmyszewicz/UILabel

Comment: Thanks for your effort, man. I tried but it didn't work. I just realized that if you take a closer look to the image that I posted, the size of the uilabel looks fine, it seems that two lines of text can fit there, but for some reason the text is not being displayed correctly

Comment: Ok, fixed. What was the solution? Erase the label and do it again from scratch, can you believe? I will add this to my post. Thanks for your help, man.