# How to fix the uilabel height as dynamic[depend upon text]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to fix the label height as dynamic to depend upon the text.

```
CGSize size = [Str sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15]}];
        CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
        NSLog(@"this is height of the label =%@",NSStringFromCGSize(adjustedSize));
```

Here i am getting the width and height ,but the width is exceed the screen size width.

what i want is that label width should be equal to my screen size and the height is vary depend upon the text ........

Comment: See my answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009311/autolayout-uilabel-not-resizing-properly-with-long-text/34009386#34009386

Comment: ok bro........ @WojtekDmyszewicz

Comment: @WojtekDmyszewicz i have created my uilabel via programatically

Comment: In my example I use constraints to solve your problem, it's possible to add the same constraints programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the label height as dynamic to depend upon the text with below code

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."];

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 20, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


UILabel *Label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[Label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
//set new frame to label.
CGRect newFrame = Label.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 10;
newFrame.origin.y = 20;
newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width - 20;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
Label.frame = newFrame;
Label.text = str;
Label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
Label.numberOfLines = 20;
Label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15];
Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:Label];

//width constraint
[Label addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Label
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1
                                                   constant:expectedLabelSize.width - 20]];

//height constraint
[Label addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Label
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1
                                                   constant: expectedLabelSize.height]];

//center constraint
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:Label
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0]];
// Top constraint
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Label
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:20]];
```

Comment: If you still have a problem with dynamic label, You need to check your custom font (OpenSans) available or not . you can use below method to check available fonts on your app.

Comment: static void dumpAllFonts() {
    
    NSLog(@"list of available fonts on your app ");
    for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

set

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[yourLabel sizeToFit];
```

Give a particular width or leading and trailing space to that label so that the width stays fixed and the height increases as per text length.

You can also set The numberOfLines through your xib file. 
1. Click on your label in the xib. 
2. On the Right hand panel below the alignment tab, you can set the numberOfLines from 1 to 0.

Comment: i have done that programatically ,so i confused to set constraints programatically

Comment: Even if you are creating your label programmatically, you can still add a width to your label and set numberOfLines = 0.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yourLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yourLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraints:@[leadingConstraint,topConstraint]]; Try using this and manipulate it in your way.

Answer (score 1):

Select your label
Click on editor and select size to fit Content

[image]

Comment: [labelName sizeToFit];

Answer (score 1):

i think your custom font create problem. you can use this code for calculate dynamic size

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.from Xib you need to set no. of line 0 for this label :

and use this method :

```
- (CGFloat)getHeightforController:(id)view{
UILabel *tempView =(UILabel *)view;
NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;

float width = tempView.frame.size.width;

width = width * ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/320);

CGSize size=[tempView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tempView.frame.size.width, 200)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : tempView.font}
                                        context:context].size;
return size.height;
}
```

call this method like:

```
label.text = @"text"
CGRect frame = cell.lblAddress.frame;
frame.size.height = [self getHeightforController:label];
label.frame = frame;
```

make sure you are setting text for your label before calling this method

Comment: i am created my uilabel via programmatically

Comment: then also you can apply this. where you created your label you need to write ' yourLabel.numberOfLines=0' and 'yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping '

Answer (score 0):

use auto layout or do like this

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
yourLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```